# python, psycopg2, and bound parameters

Tags: python

I have this guy:

```
query = 'DELETE FROM boyd.%s WHERE teamid = %s AND id = %s AND year = %s' % (statstype, '%s', '%s', '%s')
self.executequery(query, values[0:3])
```

Which strikes me as ugly. The first %s is actually supplied by the variable, the other three are bound variables: do I really need to go `% (statstype, '%s', '%s', '%s')`? Is there a more... pythonic approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use double `%%` signs, one `%` will still remain after string interpolation:

```
query = 'DELETE FROM boyd.%s WHERE teamid = %%s AND id = %%s AND year = %%s' % (statstype)
self.executequery(query, values[0:3])
```